# JavaScript in Zend and jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, zend-framework, mobile

I'm developing an application in ZF1, using jQuery Mobile. I have a form (fragment):

```
$options = array('Employee', 'Supervisor', 'Other');
$form1->addElement('select', 'role', array('multioptions' => $options);
$form1->role->setAttribs(array('onchange', 'showHide()'));
$form2->addElement('text', 'position');
```

I have a script:

```
function showHide(){
    var hide = false;
    if(document.getElementById("form1-role").value === "Employee" ||
       document.getElementById("form1-role").value === "Supervisor") {
        hide = false;
    } else {
        hide = true;
    }

    var i;
    var elements = [
        "form2-position-label",
        "form2-position-element"
    ];

    for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if(document.getElementById(elements[i]) !== null) {
            document.getElementById(elements[i]).hidden = hide;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is - when user selects 'Other' from the list the Textbox 'position' suppose to hide. Otherwise it should be visible. Everything works fine until form validation returns false - then validator messages appear and script stops working.
What is interesting - when I put `alert("hello");` to the script, it does show the alert but still doesn't hide the textbox.

Comment: Is an error being shown in your console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove your `$form1->role->setAttribs(array('onchange', 'showHide()'));` and use this (seeing as you have jQuery on the page anyway).

```
$(function(){
    $('#form1-role').on('change', function(){
        var role = $(this).val();

        $('#form2-position-label, #form2-position-element')
            .toggleClass('hidden', role !== 'Employee' && role !== 'Supervisor');
    });
});
```

This toggles a class on the target elements. So the CSS is simple:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want this to activate on the page rendering as well (i.e. if there is an error message to display), you can put `.change();` at the end of the `on` call.

```
$(function(){
    $('#form1-role').on('change', function(){
        var role = $(this).val();

        $('#form2-position-label, #form2-position-element')
        .toggleClass('hidden', role !== 'Employee' && role !== 'Supervisor');
    }).change();
});
```

This will trigger a `change` event as soon as the page renders and execute the logic within the handler.

Comment: At the beginning it didn't work, but then I figured out, that it might be ajax transition problem. Found on this page: [link](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/forms/forms-sample.html) a way to disable ajax transitions for submit button - `data-ajax="false"` attribute should be put in `<form>` tag instead of `<submit>`. Now it works good with your code (though there is of course no transition effect after clicking the submit button, but it isn't so important for me).

Thanks a lot for help!